# use secugen fingerprint reader on web for attendence system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have **Secugen Hamster pro 20** fingerprint reader device.

I want to use this fingerprint reader for student attendance on the web with PHP and mySQL.

Is there an API or SDK which I can use to:

- save fingerprint data, and
- match data for attendance.

Comment: Could you added JavaScript in this HTML

Comment: did you find any answers on these? they have an demo that is working but a shitty technical support they dont response